# Android assign data to listview

Tags: android

I read data from database and stored in array list then disply in listview. But when i add the listview it will show error message as below in logcat. I already have data in the array list.But look like the system assign array list into listview before or during connecting/executing the sql. So, the data might not assign yet to array list but system already execute the next statment because when i remove the listview statement,it can working. Why like this. I'm new in Android.

Error:
     Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0

Code:

```
 private ListView listView1;
 private  ArrayList<String> arrData = new ArrayList<String>();
 private Campaign campaign_data[] = new Campaign[]{};
 private Integer intData=0;

 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_act_performace);

    //connect to db and get data
    ConnectTask dt = new ConnectTask();
    dt.execute();

    //display data in listview
    camp mydata[] = new camp []
            {
             new camp (R.drawable.empty, "Today:"+ arrData.get(0)),
             new camp (R.drawable.empty, "This Month:"+ arrData.get(1))
            };

    CampAdapter adapter = new CampAdapter (this,R.layout.listview_header_row, mydata);
    listView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    listView1.setAdapter(adapter);
}
class ConnectTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, String>
{
    Connection con = null;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Integer... params) {
        try {
            Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://192.168.1.2/test;instance=SQLEXPRESS;user=inc;password=123456789");
            testConnection(con);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
 public void testConnection(Connection con) throws java.sql.SQLException {
        try {
            String sql = "SELECT colA FROM test";
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

            while (rs.next()) {
                arrData.add(rs.getString("colA").toString());
                intData=intData+1;
            }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Move the below code from onCreate() to ConnectTask's onPostExecute() method.

```
CampAdapter adapter = new CampAdapter (<your activity context> ,R.layout.listview_header_row, mydata); 
    listView1.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: When i move to onPostExecute it come out error. Error: this , R.layout.listview_header_row, campaign_data cannot applied to expected actual...